# Laravel Storage copy not working, how to copy a file using storage disk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-filesystem, laravel-storage

my following command works fine

```
copy($file_date['file_name_tmp_target'], $file_date['file_name_target']);
```

but when i do

```
\Storage::copy($file_date['file_name_tmp_target'], $file_date['file_name_target']);
```

or

```
\Storage::move($file_date['file_name_tmp_target'], $file_date['file_name_target']);
```

it give me an error following

> (1/1) FileNotFoundException File not found at path:
>   Library/WebServer/Documents/project_name/public/report_tmp.csv

any idea? how to just copy file using Storage disk ?

Comment: I don't know why my this question is downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you set your disk in valid way. Storage is using `config/filesystems.php` and by default uses `local` disk which is configured like this:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

so the file path you pass here should be located in `storage/app` directory.

Comment: I tried this too Storage::disk('outdoor_real_time_report_path')->copy('old','new') its same error

Comment: And what is `outdoor_real_time_report_path` - how you defined it in `config/filesystems.php`?

Comment: how to get rid of this error ?File already exists at path: outdoor_hold_report.csv

i dont want this?

Comment: no i can't delete and then copy the file. because file size is like 400 mb what if i delete the file and copy take time and meanwhile user clicks to download the file, he will face error, any better solution ?

Comment: If you just copy file on local filesystem it shouldn't take much time. However if you think it's a problem you need to create solution that would be best in your case. For example you could track each download start/end, save the new file with some other name and then in cron delete old file and put there new one when you are sure file is not downloaded. You also don't need to use exact same name for new file, so you can create new links on site and remove old files/records after some reasonable time (for example you assume downloading takes max 1h and after 1h you delete old files)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i was doing wrong

This should be the answer, addition to Marcin Answer thanks :)

```
 \Storage::disk('outdoor_real_time_report_path')->copy($file_date['file_name_tmp'], $file_date['file_name']);
```